# (ruby) does one escapse using h() in view files only for security, or in controller files as well?

Tags: html, ruby, security, filtering

I receive input in the form of URL strings (aka controller/action?example=yes), and I'm wondering if I need to escape the content of the string for security.

For example, if I assign the param to a variable:

example = params[:example].to_s

do I need to escape anything? or do I only apply h() when I put the value of :example back in the view file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing with it, if you are worried of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) , then you can trust ActiveRecord, like doing:

```
Examples.find_by_name params[:example]
```

or

```
Examples.find(:conditions=> ["name = ?", params[:example]])
```

On the other side, the common strategy of filtering is on display side, so you save the input as is, and you filter on display(views) by using `h()`.

If you still want to save some HTML input from the user like when doing in rich editors, then you have to pay extra attention to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and so you have to filter the input. One great gem for filtering HTML is [Sanitize](http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize), use it to save a modified filtered version of user input to use it in views.

Comment: Note that in the very soon future (Rails 3), all strings will be html escaped, and you need to mark a string as "safe" if you want to serve it as is. See this commit: http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9415935902f120a9bac0bfce7129725a0db38ed3